# keep getting the errors: "redefinition of typedef 'MYSTRUCT'" and "previous declaration of 'MYSTRUCT' was here"

Tags: c, error-handling, struct, declaration

i keep getting the an error that was supposed to happen if i haven't had pre-declared the structures used **before** its definition, but i did!!: "typedef struct campeonato campeonato; typedef struct jogo jogo;" (as shown in the code below). Can anyone tell me why I'm getting the following errors and what's wrong with my code:

```
c:21: error: redefinition of typedef 'campeonato'
c:5: error: previous declaration of 'campeonato' was here
c:29: error: redefinition of typedef 'jogo'
c:6: error: previous declaration of 'jogo' was here
```

and the piece of code that generates those errors is...

```
typedef struct campeonato campeonato;
typedef struct jogo jogo;

typedef struct time{
       char nome[32];
       //existe uma correspondencia entre jogos[i][] e campeonatos[i]
       jogo *jogosDeCadaCampeonato;
       campeonato *campeonatos[];
       }time;

typedef struct campeonato{
       char nome [100];
       int nro_participantes;
       int nro_jogos;
       time *times;
       jogo *jogos;
       }campeonato;

typedef struct jogo{
       time* timeA;
       time* timeB;
       time* vencedor;
       int golsA;
       int golsB;
       }jogo;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
typedef struct campeonato campeonato;
typedef struct jogo jogo;
```

Is not a forward declaration. It's a typedef. A forward declaration would simply be:

```
struct campeonato;
struct jogo;
```

As it is now, you typedef campeonato and jogo twice, hence the error.

Note that using the forward declaration will allow you to use the structs before they are defined, you'd still have to use them as `struct campeonato` in `time` and `struct jogo` in `campeonato`.

Comment: It worked Eran! I know it must've been simple for you but thank you so much mate. I'm very into java and still getting used to c. that was my first question at SO and i'm surprised with that fast answer. :-)